# Adobe-like notes on latex

Tags: notes

I'm writing my dissertation on latex, and this involves several reviews from my mentor, of course.

I currently use the package `soul` to highlight changes from the previous versions and comments, but I would like to use the same scheme he uses to annotate the suggestions he has to the text, which is annotating it with adobe reader, so it gets highlighted and a little balloon with the desired text is created like this:

[image: cute little nice balloon]

I don't know if this is adobe proprietary stuff, but I think not since it seems to work fine on others pdf viewers.

So the thing is: Is there any package that provides the possibility to create those notes into latex?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The package `pdfcomment` provides comments and `tooltip` support for `LaTeX`. The comment `icon` can be configured.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
Blabla \pdfcomment{Here is a comment}
\end{document}
```

With some highlighting and some keys changed:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pdfcomment}
\begin{document}
Blabla \pdfcomment[author={HericDenis},icon=Note,color=red]{Edit me!!!}

\pdfmarkupcomment[author={HericDenis},markup=Highlight,color=yellow]{Some text to highlight}{Here is another comment}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, that was fast! I'll try that out.

Comment: @HericDenis: I will update with the `highlight` possibility

Comment: It works, but the package probably uses hyperref or something similar, so I get those red boxes on table and picture's refs, which ain't a problem. The problem is: the first couple of times I run the document (after adding the package) the references get highlighted (but don't links properly, just goes to the beginning of the document), but on the third time, the references are all gone. So clearly there's something incompatible here.

Comment: Try to use `pdfcomment` as the last package then

Comment: When I put it as the last package, the references don't vanish, but they won't appear on the text, just the (??), and the index gets messed up as well, I get stuff like this: ~UBSUBSECTION.1.2.2.23.4

Comment: @HericDenis: Yes, but all this stuff isn't available to me. You did not provide a document to start with. Please compile three times also!

Comment: If I use `\blinddocument` etc and add an `\index` etc. I don't get any problems.

Comment: Yeah, it's kinda problematic because I use a custom .cls and plenty other packages... I'll just accept your answer since it answers it properly, but will not use it, it's causing more problems then helping me out here. But thank you anyway!

Comment: @HericDenis: I would really like to help you but custom classes are sometimes weird (sorry) and screw up the whole counter/labelling/referencing system

Comment: Yeah I know that, but I have no other way arround it ;) Thank you again!

Comment: Perhaps you could put the package order back to how it worked and change the hyperref settings.  You can turn off the boxes and set the text to black.